# Perl to compare filename starting with some specific number exist or not

Tags: perl

I need to create a Perl script to check the first four characters of the file name of all the files mentioned in a path, and compare it with a text file containing those four characters.

The idea is to check whether any file starting with a list of numbers is missing.

For Example. Files in path `D:/temp` are

```
1234-2041-123.txt
1194-2041-123.txt
3234-2041-123.txt
1574-2041-123.txt
```

I need to compare the first four letter of filename - `1234`, `1194`, `3234`, `1574` - with a text file containing the sequences `1234`, `1194`, `3234`, `1574`, `1111`, `2222` and send the output

```
File starting with 1111, 2222 is missing.
```

I hope I am clear.

I am able to take out the first four characters from the file name but cannot proceed further

```
@files = <d:/temp/*>;
foreach $file (@files) {
  my $xyz  = substr $file, 8, 4;
  print $xyz . "\n";
}
```

Comment: What's the condition for a file to be missing?

Comment: You say *"I am able to take out the first four characters from the file name"* but your code extracts the ninth through to the twelfth characters. This is `1-12` for all of the file names you list. Please confirm that you do, in fact, want to check the *first* four characters.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works by creating a hash from all of the values in the file `prefixes.txt`, then deleting elements from that hash as files are found starting with each sequence.

In addition, if any file name starts with a sequence that doesn't appear in the file then a warning is printed.

The output is simply a matter of listing all the elements of the hash that remain after this process.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %prefixes;
open my $fh, '<', 'prefixes.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  $prefixes{$_} = 1;
}

my @files = qw/
  1234-2041-123.txt
  1194-2041-123.txt
  3234-2041-123.txt
  1574-2041-123.txt
/;

for my $name (@files) {
  my $pref = substr $name, 0, 4;
  if ($prefixes{$pref}) {
    delete $prefixes{$pref};
  }
  else {
    warn qq{Prefix for file "$name" not listed};
  }
}

printf "File starting with %s is missing.\n", join ', ', sort keys %prefixes;
```

**output**

```
File starting with 1111, 2222 is missing.
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to @F. Hauri's proposed solution, I propose a hash-based solution:

```
# Get this list from the file.  Here, 'auto' and 'cron' will exist in
# /etc, but 'fake' and 'mdup' probably won't.
my @expected_prefixes = qw| auto cron fake  mdup |;

# Initialize entries for each prefix in the seed file to false
my %prefix_list;
undef @prefix_list{ @expected_prefixes };

opendir my ${dir}, "/etc";
while (my $file_name = readdir $dir ) {
    my $first_four = substr $file_name, 0, 4;
    # Increment element for the prefix for found files
    $prefix_list{$first_four}++;
}

# Get list of prefixes with no matching files found in the directory
my @missing_files = grep { ! $prefix_list{$_} } keys %prefix_list;

say "Missing files: " . Dumper(\@missing_files);
```